# How to match string in regex until a space is encounter?

Tags: regex

I have a piece of text that I need to match anything between `&lt;latex` and `&lt;/latex&gt;` but not the text `and an equivalent quantity of`

```
Which given has the same divisor of &lt;latex&gt;5&lt;/latex&gt; and an equivalent quantity of &lt;latex&gt;(5 + 2) \div 5&lt;/latex&gt;?
```

I've tried with the regex `\&lt\;(latex).+(latex)\&gt\;([^\s])` but it doesn't stop until the last `&lt;/latex&gt;`in the line.

Comment: Quantifiers are greedy by default, this means that `.+` will take the largest possible substring. If available in your regex flavor, you need to use a non-greedy quantifier to get the smallest possible substring: `.+?`

Comment: If not available, you need to play with groups, character classes and alternations to describe what is allowed until `&lt;/latex&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a non-greedy match

```
\&lt\;(latex).+?(latex)\&gt\;
```